# Header bidding - mapping placement

Tags: prebid.js, header-bidding

I am new to DFP.

I’ve got a little concern about the setup on DFP.
In my case, I include an ad unit in DFP but I don’t map its div id with an AppNexus placement on our page. Will it cause any problems?

For example: in DFP, I target inventory as “Ron of network”, but in our page, I only map some ad units with AppNexus placement ID. Any problems with this setup?

Comment: Please include the code you're working with and asking about.

Comment: please explain what DFP means

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: DFP = Doubleclick for Publishers (the adserver in this case)

Answer (score 1):

*Q: In my case I include an ad unit in DFP but I don’t map its div id with an AppNexus placement on our page. Will it cause any problems?*

`prebid.js` just won't work because it [needs](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html) this it to set key/vals targeting for your ad unit

> The key code is an identifier of this ad unit. If you’re using GPT, we
>   recommend putting in that ad unit’s slot element ID. If you don’t put
>   in the slot element ID, pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync() would not work

*Q: For example: in DFP, I target inventory as “Ron of network”, but in our page, I only map some ad units with AppNexus placement ID. Any problems with this setup?*

Looks like your header bidding setup is incorrect (if I understood your question correctly).
You need to have line items + key/vals targetings for every price bucket required, so you'll end up having dozens of line items. And yes, such line items can be “Ron of network”. Here's the [guide](http://prebid.org/adops/step-by-step.html)

If you have multiple ad units on each page - you'll need to map all of them in `prebid.js` configuration.

If you have only a single ad unit and want to use it multiple times on the page - that's also feasible, see this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dfp/2w6OxiUHOls/yFdtjBI7EwAJ)

Comment: You can use the DFP ad unit path (/123453543/adunitname) instead of the div id as long as the DFP ad unit paths are unique and not re-used on a webpage